# What is the best Git strategy when merging back a release branch into master?

Tags: git

Following the Git Flow model, consider a `release` branch branched off from `develop`.
After any required bug fixes on the `release` branch, what is best to do and why?

1. merge back `release` into `develop` and then merge back `develop` into `master`
2. merge back `release` into `develop` and also merge `release` into `master`

Thank you

Comment: The answer may depend on what `master`, `develop`, and `feature` are supposed to represent, e.g. major/minor/other versions.  You might want to add this information to your question.

Comment: https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html Aren't both cases described?

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for the link! The author seems to propose the second option. Just curious about hearing user's feedback about the first one, especially regarding possible conflicting issues when merging back `develop` to `master` (first option)

Comment: @Kamil, where do see case #1 described.  I confess that I didn't read any of the descriptions.  I just looked at the diagrams, and didn't see any case where an arrow went directly from the `develop` lane to the `master` lane without first being merged into the `release` lane.

Comment: I haven't looked at these diagrams in a while.  It's nice to see that my group is "doing it right".  That's not surprising.  It's pretty much common sense once you decide upon the existence of each of the branches.  The `hot fix` branch is an interesting place in that it holds just special cases.  Haven't done a hot fix in quite a while.

Comment: If you are using gitflow - gitflow documents the procedure to use here.  It's the one you've nu8mbered (2).  If you're not using gitflow, but just have drawn inspiration from it: There is no one "best" or "correct" branching strategy. What you should do would depend on what result you want.  Which branch to merge to `master` depends on which changes you want in `master`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual difference will be that what has been added to `develop` since `release` was branched off of it won't make it into `master` in case #2, but will in case #1.  Looking at the GitFlow diagrams, it seems that #2 is what's always done.  You don't want to merge unreleased code into `master`, so you never merge `develop` directly into `master`.  And this makes sense, right?

Note that this holds true for when you choose to merge the `release` branch as well.  You only merge the `release` branch into `master` when you do a release. So again, you don't want anything in `master` that hasn't been released.

Comment: Thank, totally makes sense. BTW doing so would violate the precise reason for which a release branch has been created...